# Httpget from webpage doesn't return content when run on Android

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to get contents of the page: http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/simulation/simulation_test.json

I am able to get the contents in my java project. Here is the code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);



    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
```

This prints the contents in my Java project.

However, when I execute this code in my Android project, I get the following in return :

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Cisco Systems Inc. Web Authentication Redirect</TITLE><META http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"><META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><META http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"><META http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=https://1.1.1.1/login.html?redirect=www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/simulation/simulation_test.json"></HEAD></HTML>
```

How can i solve this problem? why does it occur only in my Android project and not in my Java project?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it thinks you are a bot - can you set the useragent?

Comment: Did try adding User-Agent in request.setHeader(). It didnt help

Comment: You are not using the API: http://apiportal.washingtonpost.com/blog

Comment: Could it be on your end: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11647566/cisco-wireless-1111loginhtml-redirect-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref for [android client](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)

assume not useing proxy when on android connected to WIFI.

Assume that on android you are NOT using net interface for 3G/4G

Assume that you are using the android httpclient packages and not the apache httpclient.

assume that manifest has granted Web permissions.

You have to know the above in order to do much with debug.

You will get a bunch of default headers from default packages when you invoke these:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
```

You will need to either turn on logging for WIRE & HEADERS OR you will need to dump your headers for the get request so that you know exactly whats in there.

Then , compare your android generated http GET ( all headers ) to the curl test script you see below.. If your android headers are reasonably close ( dont need to be exact there can be some extras in there like 'gzip' encoding ) to the curl headers , then the android will work. The curl example shows only 3 headers and i would make a wild guess that your android client , by default, is setting 7 or 8 headers and that the WP server does not like something in the cruft of the extra headers and is redirecting to the logon.

```
@ ~$ curl --verbose  http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/simulation/simulation_test.json


* About to connect() to www.washingtonpost.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 23.204.109.48...
* connected
* Connected to www.washingtonpost.com (23.204.109.48) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wp-srv/simulation/simulation_test.json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1-DEV
> Host: www.washingtonpost.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: webserver
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 21:16:22 GMT
< Content-Length: 58187
< ETag: "e34b-52fbe4a6"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 16:54:42 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{
"posts": [
```

android httpclient 4.3 sample with HEADER logs turned on...

```
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> PUT /1/classes/MediaItem/XPdLazBUzV HTTP/1.1
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Length: 90
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> Host: api.parse.com
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> X-Parse-Session-Token: li9ds
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> X-Parse-Application-Id: 3qovv
D/ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib.headers(15360): http-outgoing-2 >> X-Parse-REST-API-Key: Theoj
D/
```